# Is it possible to set proxy header in NGINX using variable for the *header name*?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, configuration, nginx-reverse-proxy

According to the [NGINX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)

> `proxy_set_header field value` allows redefining or appending fields to the request header passed to the proxied server. The ***value*** can contain text, ***variables***, and their combinations.

So I can do

```bash
set $my_variable "some_value";
proxy_set_header x-my-header $my_variable;
```

Is it anyhow possible to use a variable for the *`field`* parameter, i.e. have the header **name** based on a variable? I want to be able to configure NGINX like

```bash
set $my_variable "x-my-header";
proxy_set_header $my_variable "some_value";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nginx documentation does not explicitly says that you can use variables for some directive parameter, generally it means you cannot. In particular you can't use variables as the header names in `add_header`, `proxy_set_header` and some other related directives. However you can do it using third party modules, e.g. `lua-nginx-module` via [`ngx.req.set_header`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_header). You can take a look at the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) bundle which includes aforementioned module and is being [packaged](https://openresty.org/en/linux-packages.html) for a wide range of OS distributions.